# By using vb.net how to format an string

Tags: vb.net

how to format this string automatically using vb.net

```
   Dim stext as string ="1A"
   Dim stext1 as string ="A1"
   Dim sout,sout1 As String
    sout= String.Format("0000", stext )
    sout1 = String.Format("0000", stext1 )
```

but iam getting output as :

```
  stext = 0000
  stext1= 0000
```

But i need an output as :

```
  stext=001A
  stext1=00A1
```

Kinldy do the needfull

Comment: Are you trying to format a Hex value?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to want [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not `String.Format` here.

What you're currently doing is taking `"0000"` and looking for placeholders to replace, but not finding any, so it just writes out `"0000"`.

What it looks like you want is your string, padded with zeroes to the left, to 4 total positions.

```
sout = stext.PadLeft(4, "0"c)
```

`String.Format` usually looks like:

```
Dim s = String.Format("Hello {0}", personName)
```

Comment: thanks you joe. But there is an twist in this solution. we dont no how input will come for us whether it can be :        stext ="1A" or stext ="A1" or stext ="1" this this case how can we know, whether to padleft or padright

Comment: is there any solution for this joe??

Comment: PadLeft puts the zeroes on the left - PadRight puts them on the right. You'll have to decide how to go from here.